# Redis Pubsub and Message Queueing

Tags: python, redis, redis-cli

My overall question is: *Using Redis for PubSub, what happens to messages when publishers push messages into a channel faster than subscribers are able to read them?*

For example, let's say I have:

- A simple publisher publishing messages at the rate of 2 msg/sec.
- A simple subscriber reading messages at the rate of 1 msg/sec.

My naive assumption would be the subscriber would only see 50% of the messages published onto Redis. To test this theory, I wrote two scripts:

**pub.py**

```
queue = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
channel = queue.pubsub()

for i in range(10): 
    queue.publish("test", i)
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

**sub.py**

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
p = r.pubsub()
p.subscribe('test')

while True:
    message = p.get_message()
    if message:
        print "Subscriber: %s" % message['data']
    time.sleep(1)
```

**Results**

- When I ran `sub.py` first, immediately followed by `pub.py`, I found that `sub.py` actually displayed all the messages (1-10), one after another with a delay of 1 second in between. My initial assumption was wrong, Redis is queuing messages. More tests needed.
- When I ran `pub.py` first, then waited 5 seconds before running `sub.py`, I found that `sub.py` only displayed the second half of the messages (5-10). I would have assumed this originally, but given my previous results, I would have thought messages were queued, which led me to the following conclusion...

**Conclusions**

- Redis server appears to queue messages for each client, for each channel.
- As long as a client is listening, it doesn't matter how fast it reads messages. As long as it's connected, messages will remain queued for that client, for that channel.

**Remaining Questions**

- Are these conclusions valid?
- If so, how long will client/channel messages remained queued?
- If so, is there a `redis-cli info` command to see how many messages are queued (for each client/channel)?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

The tests are valid, but the conclusions are partially wrong.

Redis does not queue anything on pub/sub channels. On the contrary, it tends to read the item from the publisher socket, and write the item in all the subscriber sockets, ideally in the same iteration of the event loop. Nothing is kept in Redis data structures.

Now, as you demonstrated, there is still some kind of buffering. It is due to the usage of TCP/IP sockets, and Redis communication buffers.

Sockets have buffers, and of course, TCP comes with some flow control mechanisms. It avoids the loss of data when buffers are full. If a subscriber is not fast enough, data will accumulate in its socket buffer. When it is full, TCP will block the communication and prevents Redis to push more information in the socket.

Redis also manages output communication buffers (on top of the ones of the sockets) to generate data formatted with the Redis protocol. So when the output buffer of the socket is full, the event loop will mark the socket as non writable, and data will remain in Redis output buffers.

Provided the TCP connection is still valid, data can remain in the buffers for a very long time. Now, both the socket and Redis output buffer are bound. If the subscribers are really too slow, and a lot of data accumulate, Redis will ultimately close the connection with subscribers (as a safety mechanism).

By default, for pub/sub, Redis has a soft limit at 8 MB, and a hard limit at 32 MB, per connection buffer. If the output buffer reaches the hard limit, or if it remains between the soft and hard limit for more than 60 seconds, the connection with the slow subscriber will be closed.

Knowing the number of pending messages is not easy. It can be evaluated by looking at the size of the pending information in the socket buffers, and the Redis output buffers.

For Redis output buffers, you can use the [CLIENT LIST command](http://redis.io/commands/client-list) (from redis-cli). The size of the output buffer is returned in the obl and oll fields (in bytes).

For socket buffers, there is no Redis command. However, on Linux, it is possible to build a script to interpret the content of the /proc/net/tcp file. See an example [here](https://gist.github.com/dspezia/2344181). This script probably needs to be adapted to your system.

Comment: "There are new answers for the question - click _here_ to load them" - you type faster than me and gave an amazing answer :)

Comment: Sorry :-) I was motivated by the question!

Comment: Very good answer! Is it possible to disable Redis buffers completely and receive only actual data only on the new event  (e.g. stock exchange market update) even with some loss of previous data to ensure that data is the most up to date?

Comment: No, it is not possible. The content in the buffer is already encoded in the Redis protocol, and cannot be arbitrarily cut at random locations. It would probably require to reparse the content of the buffer.

Comment: @Didier Spezia, What "C" source code file in Redis 4.0.7 contains the logic which controls 1) when TCP will block the communication and prevent Redis from pushing more information in the socket. 2) when Redis will ultimately close the connection with subscribers if the subscribers are really too slow, and a lot of data accumulates? Thank you.

Comment: Late to the party, this was a very interesting read, thanks! So from your answer @IlyaCherevkov question I am gonna assume that if I cannot prevent the buffer overflow (because my client is too slow), there is no way to prevent a disconnect of that client? I can't say throw away the buffer instead of disconnecting the client for example?

Comment: @DidierSpezia You seem quite knowledgable on redis, mind if I make you aware of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68437652/redis-listening-to-pubsub-events-and-turning-them-into-a-stream-for-more-reliab

Comment: Are there alternatives to Redis when buffering is totally undesired and unacceptable? I want to stream real-time sensor data from one robot (webcam, laser point  cloud, etc.) to multiple observers. So only the newest data is useful.

Comment: I asked a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71107276/are-there-alternatives-to-redis-when-buffering-is-undesired-and-unacceptable. Thanks for your help.