# Are there alternatives to Redis when buffering is undesired and unacceptable?

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe, producer-consumer

I want to stream real-time sensor data(webcam, laser point cloud, etc.) from one robot to multiple observers.

In this use case, only the newest data is useful. For example, when a new frame of point cloud arrives, the older ones will be useless.

Redis has nice publisher/consumer support, but it has buffers according to ([Redis Pubsub and Message Queueing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27745842/redis-pubsub-and-message-queueing/27746701#comment125348554_27746701)).

So are there better alternatives? Something like [ROS](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29)'s publishers/subscribers. They have a message queue size parameter.

```
  /**
   * The subscribe() call is how you tell ROS that you want to receive messages
   * on a given topic.
   *
   * The second parameter to the subscribe() function is the size of the message
   * queue.  If messages are arriving faster than they are being processed, this
   * is the number of messages that will be buffered up before beginning to throw
   * away the oldest ones.
   */
  ros::Subscriber sub = n.subscribe("chatter", 1000, chatterCallback);
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No. I think I have to implement the logic on the backend server. It's not very complicated. I shall share the code as a NodeJS module when it's done.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use redis list data structure for your purpose, like a queue. The list data structure in redis is made with linked list and adding a new item is O(1). Whenever your robot produces data it can put it in a list with `LPUSH` command, and when you want to get the latest item from the list use `LRANGE "key-name" 0 0`. This command will retrive the latest pushed item. Also if you want to not accumulate the data in queue, you may try to use `LTRIM` before `LRANGE` to maintain the latest records. For example `LTRIM "key-name" 0 10` will keep the records of last 10 elements. This trim interval should be set according to your observer processing speeds. ref: https://redis.io/docs/data-types/lists/